# How to call a member function of an object using that object's pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, member-functions, double-pointer

I have a Node object that has a public member function. When I have a pointer (or double pointer) in this case pointing to the original object, how do I call the member function?

Here is the member function in the Node class:

```
class Node {
public:
    ...
    int setMarked();
    ...
private:
    ...
    int marked;
    ...
};
```

And here is where I am trying to call that function:

```
Node **s;
s = &startNode; //startNode is the original pointer to the Node I want to "mark"
q.push(**s); //this is a little unrelated, but showing that it does work to push the original object onto the queue.
**s.setMarked(); //This is where I am getting the error and where most of the question lies.
```

And just in case it matters, the .setMarked() function looks like this:

```
int Node::setMarked() {
    marked = 1;
    return marked;
}
```

Comment: note that `q.push(**s);` will push a copy of the node ; your subsequent marking of `**s` won't affect the queue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dereference it twice first. Note that * binds less tightly than `.` or `->`, so you need parens:

```
(**s).setMarked();
```

Or,

```
(*s)->setMarked();
```

In your original code, the compiler was seeing the equivalent of

```
**(s.setMarked());
```

which is why it wasn't working.

Comment: This solves the original issue at hand, but for some reason now the push is not working. Is there any way this change would affect that?

Comment: Why did you change the push? This only affects calling a member function.

Comment: (Unless you're missing a semicolon after the push like your original code shows, in which case that's your problem)

Comment: I have the semicolon, and fixed it in the question, but the q.push(**s) call is throwing an error and it wasn't before I changed **s.setMarked() to (**s).setMarked().

Comment: I have no idea. The syntax I posted is surely right for calling the member function. Without knowing how push is defined I cannot possibly tell you whats wrong.

Comment: It's just the standard .push() call for a queue<T>. I think I found out what might me another issue, but thanks for the help.